# Indexar fila por posición y columna por etiqueta

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un `DataFrame` de pandas y quiero acceder a una fila y unas columnas específicas, y en concreto quiero indexar la fila por posición y la columna por etiqueta. Ahora mismo lo estoy haciendo encadenando una llamada a `.iloc` y otra a `.loc`, pero me pregunto si hay una forma más eficiente:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
d1.iloc[-1].loc[:"b"]  # Mi método actual
```

Ni `.ix`, ni `.loc` ni `.iloc` me permiten hacerlo en una sola llamada indexando filas y columnas (obtengo `KeyError` o `TypeError`). ¿Me estoy confundiendo en algo fundamental?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.ix` está construido sobre `.loc` e `.iloc`. Está basado principalmente en `.loc` pero buscará por entero siempre y cuando el eje no esté basado en enteros, en cuyo caso sólo buscará por etiqueta. De ahí el error.

En cualquier caso es más eficiente tu método actual.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing